# When are experimental parts in Openlayers considered stable?

Tags: openlayers

When are experimental parts in Openlayers considered stable? What does it take: Do they need to be included in a number of versions, be included for a certain time period, be used by a given number of sites or perhaps be formally accepted by a part of the dev team?

Comment: Hi Joseph, I've edited the question in order to make it simpler and clearer. I'm trying to figure out what procedure the Openlayers team uses when deciding whether to mark a feature as stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before answering this question, let me clarify that you can safely use parts of the API that are marked experimental. The release notes for each new release include detailed upgrade descriptions when experimental features change.

Now to answer your question, there is no strict process for this. As a rule of thumb, sometimes when the core developers get together at a conference or a code sprint, the API gets reviewed and parts that everyone is comfortable with get marked stable.